# Is there any concrete example of the local local minima for MLP?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I'm learning machine learning, and I saw some materials indicate that MLP (multilayer perceptron) may get stuck at local minima. I want to learn by doing some experiment but I searched in web for concrete example but couldn't find any. Can anyone tell me where to find such example that can be reproduced by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply build a XOR neural network via back-propagation using stochastic gradient descent. A very simple way to generate a dataset for this experiment can be:

```
X = [[randint(0, 1), randint(0, 1)] for _ in range(1000)]
y = []
for a, b in X:
    if a + b == 1:
        y.append([0, 1])
    else:
        y.append([1, 0])
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
```

You may find this SO post ([XOR neural network error stops decreasing during training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046916/my-neural-network-gets-stuck-while-training-is-this-normal)) helpful as it is related to your query.

**Others**: If you are familiar with [torch](https://github.com/torch/nn), then you can look at this [github repository](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/training.md#nn.DoItStochasticGradient) for a comprehensive example. You can generate dataset for your experiment as described [here](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/training.md#example-of-training-using-stochasticgradient) in torch. If you are not familiar with torch but interested to learn, you may consider going through this [post](http://torch5.sourceforge.net/manual/newbieTutorial.html).

**Helpful Tutorials**:
(1) [The XOR problem and solution](http://www.mind.ilstu.edu/curriculum/artificial_neural_net/xor_problem_and_solution.php)